# Handling CheckboxField in GlassMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, sitecore, glass-mapper

I am currently using Glass Mapper to map items in the sitecore tree to Model classes in C#, however I am having issues when trying to read the Checked parameter of a checkbox field on the item.

How do I read the Checked property? I have tried setting the field below to a CheckboxField data type but it has still failed to load the data I require.

Will I need to create another Model class to extract the CheckboxField template data values?

The class property definition

```
[SitecoreField("Is Gold Class Package")]
public virtual CheckboxField IsGoldClassPackage { get; set; }
```

The Razor markup

```
@foreach (var package in Model.LoyaltyPackages.LoyaltyPackageDataItems)
{
    <div vrewards-item title="@package.Title" unlocked price="@package.Points" icon="@package.Icon"
        @(package.IsGoldClassPackage.Checked == true ? goldClassAttrribute : "") >
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Glass you don't map the fields but just the values. So your domain model should look like this:

```
[SitecoreField("Is Gold Class Package")]
public virtual bool IsGoldClassPackage { get; set; }
```

And in your view you can simply get the value from the model:

```
@foreach (var package in Model.LoyaltyPackages.LoyaltyPackageDataItems)
{
    <div vrewards-item title="@package.Title" unlocked price="@package.Points" icon="@package.Icon"
        @(package.IsGoldClassPackage == true ? goldClassAttrribute : "") >
    </div>
}
```